# Find a formula for a sequence of the following character strings

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

> Given strings:
>
> 0,
>
> 020,
>
> 0208020,
>
> 0208020180208020,
>
> 0208020180208020320208020180208020,
>
> ...

I have to write a C++ program that computes the nth string. My problem is to find a rule to get the next string. Maybe i just need a little hint.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: 2, 8, 18, 32 = 1^2, 2^2, 3^2, 4^2 times 2; therefore: take the last string; append 2 n^2; append the last string again

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're copying the number you have and sticking $2n^2$ in between the copies.

Comment: Wow so quick. Thank you very much.